# running multiple queues on laravel homestead

Tags: laravel

I use laravel homestead to provision my server on my virtualbox which is vagrant. I currently use the default queue to run my jobs but after sending to a new queue it just does not get picked up probably because I don't have it set up on homestead yet. How do I set up multiple queues on laravel homestead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation :

> Since queue workers are long-lived processes, they will not pick up
>   changes to your code without being restarted. So, the simplest way to
>   deploy an application using queue workers is to restart the workers
>   during your deployment process.

to pick up your new queue, connect to your server via ssh and  restart the queue with:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

for more information check the doc  [queue-workers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment)

Comment: thanks i finally figured it out after reloading my vagrant

Comment: @daqustae make my answer as true please if it helped you